# Proof: $(x_n)_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ If $\lim x_n<t$ then $\exists \bar n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $ x_n < t, \forall n>\bar n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to prove the following fact which was used in some proof in a rather handy-wavy way. (If I have an strict upper bound for the limit eventually I have to go below it) I meant it does look intuitive, but still.

Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. If $\lim x_n<t$ then $\exists \bar n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t $ x_n < t,  \forall n>\bar n$

I tried using the definition of limit, but I am not getting the thesis:

Let $L:=\lim_n x_n$ then

$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \bar n>0,$ s.t. $|x_n-L|<\varepsilon$

Then $x_n<\varepsilon +L<  \varepsilon + t$.

**How should I proceed?**

**Edit** Two different procedures lead me to different answers: Take $ε=(t−L)/2:x_n<L+ε<(t+L)/2<t,$
which what I wanted. But if I do: $x_n<t+ε
,$ take $ε=1/m,m∈\Bbb N$
and take the limit for $m→∞
.$ The inequality becomes "non-strict": $x_n≤t
.$ I guess they are both correct, but the second one is useless.

Comment: What do you get if you use $\epsilon = \frac{t-\alpha}{2}$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $x_n <(3t-\alpha)/2 $?

Comment: I see, I'd better used it in "$x_n <\varepsilon + \alpha$"

Comment: Your intermediate $\alpha$ (such that $\lim x_n\le\alpha<t$) was irrelevant. You can assume it is equal to $\lim x_n.$ I took the liberty to simplify your post. Btw, this is a FAQ. Let us look for duplicates.

Comment: @AnneBauval Two different procedures lead me to different answers: Take $\varepsilon = (t-L)/2 : x_n <L+\varepsilon=(t+L)/2<t,$ which what I wanted. But I f I do: $x_n <L+\varepsilon$, take $\varepsilon = 1/m, m\in \mathbb{N}$ and take the limit for $m\to \infty$. The inequality becomes "non-strict":$ x_n \le t$. I guess they are both correct, but the second one is useless for what I need

Comment: @AnneBauval that's indeed a more general result that may come in handy

Comment: Your second "procedure" is flawed because if you let $\varepsilon$ vary, your $\bar n$ might tend to $+\infty.$

Comment: @AnotherUser that is useful as wel, doesany one have a proof of why when taking limits to both sides of an strict inequality $a_n <b_n$, it becomes non-strict? It's something my lecturers use all the time

Comment: This is also a FAQ. Look for duplicates on this site, or ask your friends Google or [approach$0.$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim%20x_n%3C%5Clim%20y_n%24&p=1) E.g. [Find an example of two convergent sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$, where $x_n < y_n$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but $\lim x_n \not < \lim y_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194358)